# Acomodar las etiquetas en gplot (que se centren al objeto que nombran)

Tags: r

Estoy dándole formato a un grafico de análisis de red social (ploteado con gplot) y me interesa que las etiquetas de cada nodo aparezcan sobre cada uno. Alguien que me pueda apoyar?

```
"gplot(rb,gmode="graph",
 edge.col=linecol_pal[edge_cat],
 vertex.cex=((log(deg))*1.3),
 vertex.col = 4,
 displaylabels=TRUE,
 label.cex=0.5,
 pad=0.2,
 label.col="darkblue",
 mode="fruchtermanreingold",
 main="Red de vinculación")"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido user206172 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedo reproducir tu problema, mismo código, obviamente otros datos, y las etiquetas aparecen cerca de los nodos. Trata de compartir los datos de alguna forma, por ejemplo pegando la salida de `dput(rb)`

Answer (score 0):

No es posible reproducir tu problema pero leyendo el manual de gplot creo que he encontrado una solución. Puedes usar el argumento "label.pos" para elegir la posición de las etiquetas en la figura. Si quieres que salgan en los vertices, me parece que tienes que poner "label.pos>=5". No entiendo bien porque esto no te sale por defecto...suerte!

label.pos
position at which labels should be placed, relative to vertices. 0 results in labels which are placed away from the center of the plotting region; 1, 2, 3, and 4 result in labels being placed below, to the left of, above, and to the right of vertices (respectively); and label.pos>=5 results in labels which are plotted with no offset (i.e., at the vertex positions).